# "Words were different when they (lived / were living) inside of you"

Tags: tense, past-tense, past-continuous

> “Words were different when they lived inside of you.”
>
> ― Benjamin Alire Sáenz, Aristotle and Dante Discover the Secrets of the Universe.

Shouldn't it be "...when they were living inside of you."?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is correct. There is no grammatical requirement for clauses following the "when" conjunction to be in the continuous tense, especially not with verbs like "live" that already indicate a state, not an action.